# Using Windows Authentication how to redirect all initial request to a specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, form-authentication

I have a asp.net web application running on Windows Authentication mode. My requirement is whatever page(urls) user requested first time(session start) it shoud redirected to LandingPage.aspx. Can anybody suggest how to redirect all initial request to a specific page(LandingPage.aspx) using Windows Authentication ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this [Windows Authentication Redirection](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t765416-redirect-to-default-page-using-windows-authentication.html)

Comment: Can't you use Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect?

Comment: I tried this in Web.Config but not working as expected         <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms
         name=".Test"
         loginUrl="Landingpage.aspx"
         defaultUrl="default.aspx"
         protection="All"
         timeout="30"
         path="/"
         requireSSL="false"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
         domain="companySite"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="true">
        <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
      </forms>
      <passport redirectUrl="internal" />
    </authentication>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `Session_Start` method of `Global.asax` file and redirect to your landing page.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("LandingPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I can not use this, because on some pages i have disabled Sessions. So when user directly hit session disabled page this code wont work.